# Location based redirect using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, centos

Is it possible to perform redirect only on a specific list of IPs using .htaccess? What I am trying to do is redirect all traffic from one country to another domain and no redirection for every others. Is it possible to do that using .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can but it might be complicated for some countries with many ranges.

A simple example is North Korea unique IP range `175.45.176.0 – 175.45.179.255`:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^175\.45\.17[6-9]\.[0-9]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/ [L,R=301]
```

It would be easier to use a local library like [ip2location](http://lite.ip2location.com/database-ip-country) and do the redirection in your code.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up creating a PHP script to do this. It is more effective and seems to be working for me.